# Intersection of subgroup cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, intersection-theory

Let H and K both be subgroups of G. Show that for all a ∈ G we have Ha ∩ Ka = (H ∩ K)a?

Considering H and K are subgroups I thought there could be two general cases; H ∩ K = {1} or H ∩ K not equal to {1} (i.e. something of higher order)

For H ∩ K = {1}, 
Clearly (H ∩ K)a = 1a = G. But how do I show Ha ∩ Ka = G??

For the other case; 
if x ∈ H and x ∈ K then surly x ∈ H ∩ K.
So, xa ∈ (H ∩ K)a.
Then, xa ∈ Ha and xa ∈ Ka.
Thus, xa ∈ Ha ∩ Ka.

I'm not sure if this is even the right way to attack this question; can anybody help?

Comment: One needs to see that for $x \ne y$, $xa \ne ya$.

Comment: If $x\in H\cap K$ what can you say about $xa$? If $ha=ka$ what can you say about $h$ and $k$?

Comment: If x ∈ H ∩ K what can you say about xa? 
xa ∈ (H ∩ K)a?? 

If ha=ka what can you say about h and k?
h is not equal to k (similar to what 'vnd' said)

If correct, then yes i understand all that but in terms of writing this out i'm very confused